# How to launch an animation defined in a Style from a Control implementing it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, styles, storyboard

I created a state in a Style named "Error" with an attached animation in a storyboard.

I would like to be able to launch that animation from a Control that uses that Style, whenever a certain condition is met.

For example, when a property in my View's DataContext is set to a certain value.

How exactly can I launch the storyboard defined in the control's Style ?

Comment: everything is explained for you here: http://blog.smoura.com/playing-storyboards-on-datatriggers-to-animate-a-path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a class that will hold all of my controls' validation dependency properties:

```
public class ValidationProperties
{
     #region IsValid Dependency Property

    /// <summary>
    /// An attached dependency property which provides an
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValidProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="IsValidProperty"/> for a given
    /// <see cref="DependencyObject"/>, which provides an
    /// </summary>
    public static bool GetIsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsValidProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the attached <see cref="IsValidProperty"/> for a given
    /// <see cref="DependencyObject"/>, which provides an
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetIsValid(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsValidProperty, value);
    }

     #endregion IsValid Dependency Property

    static ValidationProperties()
    {
        // Register attached dependency property
        IsValidProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsValid",
                                                            typeof(bool),
                                                            typeof(ValidationProperties), 
                                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));
    }
}
```

Following this, I modified the style to launch the animation depending on the value of that property for the control that uses the style:

```
(...)

<Trigger Property="AttachedProperties:ValidationProperties.IsValid" Value="false">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ControlIsInvalid}"/>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>

(...)
```

I finally bound the Dependency Property on the Control that uses the Style to the value in the Model (via the View-Model):

```
<TextBox x:Name="UsernameTextbox"
       (...)
       AttachedProperties:ValidationProperties.IsValid="{Binding SessionHandler.SessionUser.UsernameIsValid}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code behind of the control just do

```
Storyboard myStoryboard = this.FindResource("NameOfMyStoryBoard") as Storyboard;

if(myStoryboard != null)
{
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

If your Storyboard is not set as a resource but is embedded in your style, declare it as a resource and reference it in your style.

MSDN documentation: [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, your solution is good but I can't trigger the animation from the code-behind since the value of the property is modified by the model without the View knowing about it. In other words, the View is never aware of when the value changes. I developed a solution using Dependency Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is how you do it from XAML using Triggers:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyStyle">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="MyGetFocusAnimation">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     To="50"
                                     Duration="0:0:.3" />
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="MyLoseFocusAnimation">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     To="30"
                                     Duration="0:0:.3" />
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyGetFocusAnimation}" />
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyLoseFocusAnimation}" />
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"
                         Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyGetFocusAnimation}" />
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyLoseFocusAnimation}" />
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

After you have defined the style like above you simply need to tell the button what style to use:

```
<Button Content="Content" Height="20" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Louie; The problem I had was with triggering an animation in a Style depending on the value of a property that was in my Model. In other words, the trigger property were not built in (ex: IsMouseOver, etc.). I developed a solution which uses Dependency Properties.